# How to convert a column with type int4range to an integer on PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to convert a column with datatype int4range to integer but I'm getting an error message. What I'm doing wrong or how I can convert it from int4range to integer?

Here's the query I'm using:

```
ALTER TABLE cat_tipos_cierre ALTER COLUMN idu_tipo_cierre TYPE integer USING idu_tipo_cierre::integer;
```

And here's the error message I receive after executing that query:

```
ERROR:  no se puede convertir el tipo int4range a integer
SQL state: 42846
```

Which translate to: ERROR: int4range type cannot be converted to integer

I'm using pgAdmin v.4

Comment: An integer range is ... well... a range of integers. Range 1..10 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. How should 10 integer values be casted into one single value?

Comment: I want to change the column data type because i used the wrong data type, the table it's currently empty, it's there a way to change it without having it to drop it and create it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=01a9d718f1b71883fed26ae6f819142c)

If the table is empty, you can simply use any function that is defined for int ranges and which gives out an integer, for example `lower()`

```
ALTER TABLE cat_tipos_cierre 
ALTER COLUMN idu_tipo_cierre 
    TYPE integer 
    USING lower(idu_tipo_cierre);
```